# KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "saved_models\\dataweights.{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5". Reason: \'val_accuracy\''

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I already tried changing val_acc to val_accuracy however it didn't help the error message.
I changed it in both

keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(saved_weight,monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq=2)

and os.path.join(P_MODELSAVE, 'dataweights.{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5')

It's running on Jupyter Notebook and tensorflow 2.3.0 is in use.

This is the full error message:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _get_file_path(self, epoch, logs)
   1329       # placeholders can cause formatting to fail.
-> 1330       file_path = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)
   1331     except KeyError as e:

KeyError: 'val_accuracy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-918d482685ad> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(train_noisy_batches,
      2                     steps_per_epoch = train_batches.samples // batch_size,
      3                     epochs=epochs,
      4                     verbose=1,
      5                     validation_data=val_noisy_batches,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1101               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
   1102               end_step = step + data_handler.step_increment
-> 1103               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(end_step, logs)
   1104         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
   1105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
    438     """
    439     if self._should_call_train_batch_hooks:
--> 440       self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
    441 
    442   def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs)
    287       self._call_batch_begin_hook(mode, batch, logs)
    288     elif hook == 'end':
--> 289       self._call_batch_end_hook(mode, batch, logs)
    290     else:
    291       raise ValueError('Unrecognized hook: {}'.format(hook))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _call_batch_end_hook(self, mode, batch, logs)
    307       batch_time = time.time() - self._batch_start_time
    308 
--> 309     self._call_batch_hook_helper(hook_name, batch, logs)
    310 
    311     if self._check_timing:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _call_batch_hook_helper(self, hook_name, batch, logs)
    340       hook = getattr(callback, hook_name)
    341       if getattr(callback, '_supports_tf_logs', False):
--> 342         hook(batch, logs)
    343       else:
    344         if numpy_logs is None:  # Only convert once.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
   1238   def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
   1239     if self._should_save_on_batch(batch):
-> 1240       self._save_model(epoch=self._current_epoch, logs=logs)
   1241 
   1242   def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _save_model(self, epoch, logs)
   1280       logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1281       self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
-> 1282       filepath = self._get_file_path(epoch, logs)
   1283 
   1284       try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in _get_file_path(self, epoch, logs)
   1330       file_path = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)
   1331     except KeyError as e:
-> 1332       raise KeyError('Failed to format this callback filepath: "{}". '
   1333                      'Reason: {}'.format(self.filepath, e))
   1334     self._write_filepath = distributed_file_utils.write_filepath(

KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "saved_models\\dataweights.{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5". Reason: \'val_accuracy\''
```

My model.compile code is:

```
model.compile(optimizer=model_opt, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My model.fit code is:

```
model.fit(train_noisy_batches, steps_per_epoch = train_batches.samples // batch_size, 
epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=val_noisy_batches, validation_steps = train_batches.samples // batch_size, 
callbacks=[modelchk, tensorboard, csv_logger], use_multiprocessing=False)
```

I don't really know how to fix this in the code or if this is a bigger issue. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the full code for model.compile and model.fit

Comment: you can refer this "https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656700/13068833"


In ModelCheckpoint, formatted name of filepath argument, can only be contain: epoch + keys in logs after epoch ends.
Log keys: ['loss', 'mean_absolute_error', 'val_loss', 'val_mean_absolute_error']