# KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: Reason: \'lr\''

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback

I recently switched form Tensorflow 2.2.0 to 2.4.1 and now I have a problem with `ModelCheckpoint` callback path. This code works fine if I use an environment with tf 2.2 but get an error when I use tf 2.4.1.

```
checkpoint_filepath = 'path_to/temp_checkpoints/model/epoch-{epoch}_loss-{lr:.2e}_loss-{val_loss:.3e}'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath, monitor='val_loss')

history = model.fit(training_data, training_data,
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=32,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(validation_data, validation_data),
                    verbose=verbose, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Error:

> KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "path_to/temp_checkpoints/model/epoch-{epoch}_loss-{lr:.2e}_loss-{val_loss:.3e}". Reason: 'lr''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), formatted name of `filepath` argument, can only be contain: **`epoch` + keys in `logs` after epoch ends**.

You can see available keys in logs like this:

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("Log keys: {}".format(keys))

model.fit(..., callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

If you run code above, you will see something like this:

```
Log keys: ['loss', 'mean_absolute_error', 'val_loss', 'val_mean_absolute_error']
```

Which shows you available keys you can use (plus `epoch`) and **`lr` is not available for you** (You have used 3 keys: `epoch`, `lr` and `val_loss` in `filepath` name).

---

**Solution:**

You can add learning rate to logs yourself:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs.update({'lr': K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr)})
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("Log keys: {}".format(keys)) #you will see now `lr` available

checkpoint_filepath = 'path_to/temp_checkpoints/model/epoch-{epoch}_loss-{lr:.2e}_loss-{val_loss:.3e}'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath, monitor='val_loss')

history = model.fit(training_data, training_data,
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=32,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(validation_data, validation_data),
                    verbose=verbose, callbacks=[checkpoint, CustomCallback()])
```